# Karate Test Framework with Spring Webflux and Reactive API

Tags: karate

Can Karate Test Framework work with Spring Webflux where return type is Mono<> and Flux<> Objects rather than the json string. Any refernce would be helpful.

Comment: This might help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pSk9oQ6VwMc

Comment: Thanks but Junit testing with Spring Webflux I am aware of. What I am really looking for an integration with Karate Test Framework

Comment: Any reason you want to use Karate? Karate is a http/json based framework. Do you have a http/json based API you want to test?

Answer (score -1):

Note that typical Karate usage is at the HTTP layer for REST / GraphQL - so it doesn't matter what the underlying technology is at all. So please re-check what your project requirements are.

There are plenty of examples and tutorials for Spring Boot - just do a search.

That said - Karate has very good Java interop and that may be the solution in this case. I don't know of any examples. But please refer to these answers and that should get you started:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62826394/143475

[Karate: Convert string to karate native variable in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62636729/143475)